# Use purrr::map to analyze lme4::lmer subjects using agricolae::HSD.test

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, lme4

I am having trouble understanding how to use map to apply a function that will analyze the data of individual subjects in my data

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
library(agricolae)
```

This is the model I start with

```
fm <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```

I can look at the data of individuals:

```
glimpse(ss <- sleepstudy %>%
    nest(-Subject) %>%
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(Reaction ~ Days, data = .)),
        results = map(fit, tidy)))
```

I can take an element of ss$fit and apply HSD.test to it

```
glimpse(hsd <- HSD.test(ss$fit[[1]], trt = 'Days'))
```

But when I try to use map, I get errors. Here are the two forms I used:

```
rm(ss)
glimpse(ss <- sleepstudy %>%
    nest(-Subject) %>%
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(Reaction ~ Days, data = .)),
        results = map(fit, HSD.test(., trt = 'Days'))))

glimpse(ss <- sleepstudy %>%
    nest(-Subject) %>%
    mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(Reaction ~ Days, data = .)),
        results = map(fit, HSD.test(fit, trt = 'Days'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following -

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
library(agricolae)
library(broom)

sleepstudy %>%
  nest(data = -Subject) %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(Reaction ~ Days, data = .)),
         results = map(fit, ~HSD.test(., trt = 'Days')))

#   Subject data              fit    results
#   <fct>   <list>            <list> <list> 
# 1 308     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 2 309     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 3 310     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 4 330     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 5 331     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 6 332     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 7 333     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 8 334     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
# 9 335     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#10 337     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#11 349     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#12 350     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#13 351     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#14 352     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#15 369     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#16 370     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#17 371     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
#18 372     <tibble [10 × 2]> <lm>   <group>
```